# Перекодировать все кириллические файлы

Tags: файлы, кодировка, bash, linux

Есть папка со множеством flac+cue, хочу перекодировать все кириллические cue файлы в utf-8.
Список файлов которые нужно перекодировать получаю командой

```
find /path/to/folder -iname '*.cue' -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | grep -Eo '^.+ charset=iso-8859-1'|grep -Eo '^.+ *:'|grep -o '.*[^:]'
```

список получается адекватно, как теперь мне всё это добро прогнать через iconv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А можно и без промежуточного файла

```
#!/bin/sh

Cvt ()
{
    while read x
    do
        iconv -f $1 -t $2 "$x" >  "$x.$$"
        mv "$x.$$" "$x"
    done
}

find /path/to/folder -iname '*.cue' -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | \
  grep -Eo '^.+ charset=iso-8859-1'|grep -Eo '^.+ *:'|grep -o '.*[^:]' \
  | Cvt cp1251  utf8
```

через конвейер на свою функцию

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in `find /path/to/folder -iname '*.cue' -print0 | xargs -0 file -i | grep -Eo '^.+ charset=iso-8859-1'|grep -Eo '^.+ *:'|grep -o '.*[^:]'` ; do
  cat $f | iconv -f <кодировка> -t utf-8 > $f.tmp
  mv $f.tmp $f
done
```

Comment: файлам с пробелами в именах каюк.

Comment: Верно, забыл взять $f в кавычки

Comment: нет, 

    $ for f in `echo -e 'test\ntest 1\ntest 2\n'`;do echo "$f";done
    test
    test
    1
    test
    2

Comment: По пробелам разделяет, и на следующую строку переноса нет(

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблему решил тем что сначала построчно пишу в файл пути к файлам, потом читаю построчно через cat fileWithList | while read line, проблем не возникает, всем спасибо